# android studio avd manager invalid option -- '-enable-whpx'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools, avd-manager

I facing an error while running any emulator with android studio avd manager:

```
...AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator/emulator-x86.exe: invalid option -- '-enable-whpx'
```

- android studio version is 3.1.3
- android emulator version is 27.3.9
- Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform are active on my windows 10
- and the `WindowsHypervisorPlatform = on` flag is set `...sdk\emulator\lib/advancedFeatures.ini`

this is a part of verbose mode:

```
emulator: Checking whether Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is available.
emulator: Could not load library WinHvPlatform.dll
emulator: WHPX is either not available or not installed.
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: HAXM version 7.2.0 (4) is installed and usable.
```

Windows Hypervisor Platform is checked in the windows features and the `WinHvPlatform.dll` is present in `C:\Windows\System32`

how can i enable or install WHPX ?

Comment: Did you find a sollution for this problem?  If so, please post the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Maarten checkout my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem solved by simply changing the emulator engine.

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) you can specify the emulator engine with the `-engine` flag. the mentioned error occur using the `classic` engine. when i changed the engine to `auto` or `qemu2` the emulator started with no error. to change the engine go to `.../sdk/emulator` directory with the command line and run:

```
emulator.exe -list-avds
```

this will output you virtual devices name

then run:

```
emulator.exe -avd YOUR_DEVICE_NAME -engine qemu2
```

or

```
emulator.exe -avd YOUR_DEVICE_NAME -engine auto
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried 
emulator.exe -avd YOUR_DEVICE_NAME -engine qemu2 
or
 emulator.exe -avd YOUR_DEVICE_NAME -engine auto
not working

Comment: @Dmarp did you replaced YOUR_DEVICE_NAME with your device name?